# Durability of writes between fsync() calls

Tags: linux, fsync

A call to `fsync()` ensures that the data written by any completed calls to `write()` on the same file descriptor are durable, in the sense that they will be readable even if the system subsequently crashes and restarts.

It's also the case that the effects of calls to `write()` may be reordered on their way to disk, so if you do not `fsync()` then you may see the effects of later calls to `write()` but not earlier ones.

As I understand it, appending to a file seems reasonably safe even between `fsync()` calls: after a crash the resulting file is whatever was `fsync()`ed plus maybe some initial subsequence of whatever else was written. There is no possibility of the file containing later writes and not earlier ones, or of containing junk data instead of something actually written (possibly depending on which filesystem you're using and what options you've chosen, e.g. `ext3` and `ext4` have `data=ordered` vs `data=writeback`).

What is much less clear is the effects of a crash while overwriting some blocks in the middle of a file. In that case is it possible that any subset of the blocks may be seen to be overwritten when reading the file after a crash? If so, is there in fact any way to safely update the middle of a file, or do you basically have to rely on an append-only log for durability?

Are there *any* guarantees about `write()` calls that are in-flight at the time of the `fsync()` call, or which are started afterwards? Where would I go to find out the authoritative source of these guarantees?

Comment: "As I understand it, appending to a file seems reasonably safe" -- I wouldn't count on that. If you're appending multiple blocks worth of data, there's nothing in principle to forbid the system from first writing a block that comes "later" in the file, and after that writing a block that comes "earlier" in the file. (There might be fragmentation involved, as well as reordering done by the disk and not just the filesystem, etc.)

Comment: `In that case is it possible that any subset of the blocks may be seen to be overwritten` :Exactly. **any** subset (of the dirty blocks) may have been written. And the *other* subset may not have been written.

Comment: @ikkachu Hence my comment about it "depending on ... filesystem ... options". I think that `data=ordered` gives exactly that guarantee, whereas I think you're right if `data=writeback`.

Comment: @wildplasser: so are there any guarantees in that case? For instance, is every byte in the file either the old value or the new one, or could it take some other value too?

Comment: I suspect that the data=ordered FS-option just disables the elevator seek, or the shuffle(scatter-gather)  performed at the disk level. But there still is an LRU buffer layer above it. (you could check the source. Linux is open source)

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm afraid I don't know what many of those words mean in the context of this question​. Reading the source tells me what happens now, but not what might happen next year when some other optimization is applied, which is why I'm looking for specs.

Comment: `write() calls that are in-flight at the time of the fsync() call, or which are started afterwards?` These are two different cases. fsync() is supposed to return *after* all pending writes are committed to disk. writes that occur *after* the fsync() are part of the next *transaction* . And the *order* of writes (to disk) is not guaranteed.

Comment: @joop: Interesting, I did not know that. I can't find anything to that effect in the docs, but if you can point me to a reference for that then I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: [but it is in fact a bit more complicated: fsync() applies to all the dirty blocks of a *single* file (open within a *single* process); other processes may have touched the same blocks, etc]